# How are status signals such as ALE set?

Tags: clock, microprocessor, 8085

I am currently learning about the 8085 Microprocessor as a part of my coursework. When I was studying about Timing Diagrams, I got a doubt that, how are these status signals such as \$ALE\$, \$\overline{RD}\$ ,\$\overline{WR}\$, \$S_{0}\$, \$S_{1}\$ set beforehand, i.e., before an operation such as Opcode Fetch? I guess it might be due to the Control and Timing Unit, but I don't know how it does it.

Comment: Has your course covered the concept of [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)s yet? That's what the "Control and Timing Unit" is -- it just goes through a sequence of states and drives those signals high and low at the appropriate times.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes It has been covered. So I think the reason boils down to, as a  instruction is being executed, it starts to execute a set of sub instructions, which in turn sends the tasks to Control and Timing Unit, which then drives those signals right ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sends the tasks". It all really starts with the CTU, which is driving the memory interface -- as well as internal signals to the ALU and registers -- to fetch and then execute instructions. It "knows" (i.e., it's built into the CTU's own logic) which instructions require additional memory cycles for reading/writing operands, etc.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ok, Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the control and status signals are generated by the timing and control block.

They are just a sequence of signals how to do a bus cycle when required, such as bus memory read or write, opcode read, or Io read or write, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Microprocessors from this era are "microcoded", which means each conventional instruction is carried out by executing a sequence of internal microinstructions which are typically represented at an even lower level. This segment of this video gives a good explanation of what microinstructions typically do: https://youtu.be/xx7Lfh5SKUQ?t=1713

The historical reason for this setup is to allow changes to the instruction set by altering the microcode, with relatively few changes to the electrical structure of the device.

The actual instructions given by the programmer influence which steps are executed, but the instruction fetch steps are always the same. Thus the processor can do the few steps needed to get the instruction without anything already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the video